# How can you test if a player's scoreboard score has gone up with /execute?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it so that when a player jumps, their xp goes up. I have already set up the scoreboard command (`/scoreboard objectives add jump minecraft.custom:jump "Jumps"`) and I am also trying to figure out how to use /`execute` to see if that score has increased, and if so, run `/xp add @p 1 level`. (Using `/execute as` would be preferable because then I wouldn't have to specify what player to add the xp to.)

Answer (score 1):

First add another scoreboard which will keep track of the Jumps scoreboard

```
/scoreboard objectives add prevJump dummy
```

Now we will check if jum is higher than the last time we checked

```
/execute as @e if score @s prevJump < @s jump run tag @s add addXpLevel
```

Then we update prevJump

```
/xp add @e[tag=addXpLevel] 1 level

/scoreboard players add @e[tag=addXpLevel] prevJump 1
```

/tag @e remove addXpLevel

This will also give you 2 levels if you would jump twice in the same frame. This might be more usefull for other uses.